# Android bottom navigation not changing destination

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph, android-bottomnavigationview

I was trying to implement a simple bottom navigation view using android's navigation, but I think I'm missing a step.

Here's what I did:

At first I created four fragments. These fragments contain only a text view.

Then I created a navigation graph. The code is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.baba_abdullah.Project.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addBooksFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.AddBooksFragment"
        android:label="fragment_add_books"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_books" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chatFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.ChatFragment"
        android:label="fragment_chat"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

Menu file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="@string/home_menu_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_book_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24"
        android:title="@string/add_book_menu_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/chat_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_chat_bubble_outline_24"
        android:title="@string/chat_menu_title"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
        android:title="@string/profile_menu_title"/>
</menu>
```

Inside the layout file of MainActivity, I added a FragmentContainer that would serve as NavHostFragment and a BottomNavigationView in the following way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And in the MainActivity, I added the following lines to tie them up together:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container);
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
    }
```

Now, when I click on other menu item, it doesn't get selected and the destination view isn't changed either.

You can check the [screen recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRL5kWH5L3TaqRsulBLI2E1leuX0nbsd/view?usp=sharing) of the bahaviour of the output app.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to connect bottom navigation id of fragments most be equal with menu id, here is how need to be your navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="com.baba_abdullah.Project.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/add_book_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.AddBooksFragment"
        android:label="fragment_add_books"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_books" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chat_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.ChatFragment"
        android:label="fragment_chat"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.Project.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Menu file replace menu items id with fragment id's. e.g

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:title="@string/home_menu_title"/>
```